# Set values between indexes to value - Python

Tags: python

I have a list, `temp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` If I want to set the values between index 1 and 4 to 9, what is the best way to do this? Obviously a simple for loop would do the trick, but can splicing be used here?

Something like `temp[1:4] = 9`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use :

```
 temp[1:4] = [9] * 3
```

Or:

```
temp[1:4] = [9,9,9]
```